# How to disable the display of the charts with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I display a charts with radio button and I want to add a radio button to disable the charts display and display a text. I search but I didn't find anything. I don't know how to do it if someone could help me find the solution.

I use this code to display the text :

```
function disp_plot_msg () {
    var msg = '<p id = "graphic_msg" class = "msg_text">' + 'Charts not display' + '</p>';
    if ($("#graphic_msg").hasClass("msg_text"));
    else
        $("#graphic").append(msg);
}
```

I use `.hasClass` to know if the text is display. I have another function to make the charts. (The demo of the Highcharts I use : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/))

Comment: Hi! Would you mind to include a minimal working example of your problem. This way we can get a better grasp of your issue and help you solve it! See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RamizWachtler I add the code I use to display my text but I can dislay more code of my project and I share the JSFIDDLE of  Highcharts demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show or hide a chart by setting `display` CSS style:

```
document.getElementById('chartOption').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = "none";
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ohg2c965/

Comment: Your method it's very interesting but in my case I can't use it.

Comment: Hi @SebCollard, Can I ask why? Do you want to completely delete the chart instead of hiding it?

Comment: In my case I realized  it's better to delete the charts.

Comment: Ok, so you can use `destroy` method on the chart: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy

Comment: Yeah, I find this option today I use now

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to remove an element by id, so I use this technic in my function that display the text.

Example :

```
document.getElementById('container').remove();
```